# Dagger2 How can I inject based on a java class?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, dagger, dagger-2

I have an enum with a bunch of classes that are, currently, being created using the `newInstance()` method on the `Class` object.  I would like to start using dependency injection here.

With the original dagger I could have said `ObjectGraph#get(item.getClazz())`. Is there a way to achieve something similar with Dagger2?  (I'm really liking the dagger2 interface and would prefer not to have to go back to dagger1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dagger 2 doesn't have any built-in mechanism for getting instances via `Class` objects.

Given your sample code, I would guess that your enum looks something like:

```
enum Item {
  ONE(A.class),
  TWO(B.class);

  private final Class<?> clazz;
  private Item(Class<?> clazz) { this.clazz = clazz; }
  Class<?> getClazz() { return clazz; }
}
```

In order to get calling code that behaves similarly to the version you suggested with `ObjectGraph`, you need a `@Component` with methods for each of the types referenced by `Item`.

```
@Component
interface MyComponent {
  A getA();
  B getB();
}
```

Now, you can update `Item` to delegate to MyComponent instead and remove the need for the class literals altogether.

```
enum Item {
  ONE {
    @Override A getObject(MyComponent component) {
      return component.getA();
    } 
  },
  TWO {
    @Override B getObject(MyComponent component) {
      return component.getB();
    }
  };

  abstract Object getObject(MyComponent component);
}
```

Now, rather than `ObjectGraph#get(item.getClazz())`, you can just call `item.getObject(myComponent)` for the same effect.